# HaProxy - How to configure a frontend bound to port X that passes traffic on port Y to the default backend

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

I'm trying to configure a `frontend` bound to port X, but I want to pass the traffic to my `backend` on port Y.
For example, let's say X=1337 and Y=8000, I want to basically have something like :

```
frontend myfrontend
  bind *:1337
  # some directive to pass traffic on port 8000
  default_backend mybackend

backend mybackend
  server myserver SERVER_IP
```

Keep in mind that my actual current config looks like this (minus irrelevant sections) :

```
defaults
  mode tcp
  default_backend mybackend
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
  errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
  errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
  errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
  errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
  errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
  errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend myfrontend1
  # for example here I want to bind to 3000 and forward to 30000, instead of binding to 30000 directly
  bind *:30000

frontend myfrontend2
  # for example here I want to bind to 4000 and forward to 30100, instead of binding to 30100 directly
  bind *:30100

# and many other frontends...

backend mybackend
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 PRIVATE_IP1_HERE
  server server2 PRIVATE_IP2_HERE
```

It's basically a Kubernetes cluster, server1 and server2 are nodes I'm load balancing. And because I'm using NodePorts for my services, I'm restricted to ports 30000-32767 only.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the backend port, listing your servers:

```
frontend myfrontend1
  bind *:1337
  mode tcp
  use_backend mybackend

backend mybackend1
  mode tcp
  option tcp-check
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 PRIVATE_IP1_HERE:8080 check
  server server2 PRIVATE_IP2_HERE:8080 check
```

Although if you have multiple frontends, that should connect different ports on the same set of servers: you would need to define separate backends:

```
frontend myfrontendN
  bind *:1337
  mode tcp
  use_backend mybackendN

backend mybackendN
  mode tcp
  option tcp-check
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 PRIVATE_IP1_HERE:N check
  server server2 PRIVATE_IP2_HERE:N check
```

Comment: I've thought of this solution before and so I thought maybe there was easier way to achieve what I wanted.  
Anyway I guess it's not that bad to define as much backends as frontends.  
Though I have to ask, this new setup shoudn't have a negative effect on load balancing, right?

Comment: No. In some cases, you could simplify this configuration using one frontend with several backends -- usually checking for the http host header, in your frontend block, and redirecting clients to the proper backend

Comment: That does sound like a good plan, but in my case the services running on my backend servers aren't all HTTP, some of them are plain TCP services.
If it helps visualizing my setup a bit better, the k8s cluster hosts cybersecurity challenges (for CTF), and so some intendedly vulnerable services are meant to be connected to with netcat or other similar programs.
Thank you for the answers nevertheless, this was helpful.